# What's wrong in this reasoning of $l_\infty$ separability?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, fake-proofs

While solving a problem, related to functional analysis, I've accidentally got a "proof" of $l_\infty$ being separable, tried to find a fault in it (as the result isn't true), but didn't succeed in it. This "proof" is given below, any idea of what's wrong?

1. $c_o^* = l_1$
2. $c_0 \subset l_\infty$
3. (follows from 2) $l_\infty^* \subseteq c_0^*$
4. (follows from 1 and 3) $l_\infty^* \subseteq l_1$
5. $l_1$ is separable
6. (follows from 4 and 5, as both $l_\infty^*$ and $l_1$ are metric spaces) $l_\infty^*$ is separable
7. (follows from 6, as $l_\infty$ is normed space) $l_\infty$ is separable

Comment: How does 3. follow from 2.?

Comment: @DavidMitra: from 2. follows, that each continuous functional on $l_\infty$ can be narrowed to be a continuous functional on $c_0$ - and it's the same as the third statement.

Comment: @DavidMitra: as each functional on $l_\infty$ is also a functional on $c_0$, the set of functionals on $c_0$ includes the set of functionals on $l_\infty$.

Comment: Many different functionals on $\ell_\infty$ will restrict to the same functional on $c_0$. That is, there exist $f, g \in \ell_\infty^*$ such that $f \neq g$ but $f|_{c_0}=g|_{c_0}$. In fact for each $f$ there will be infinitely many $g$ which have the same restriction to $c_0$ as $f$.

Comment: $\mathbb R\subset \mathbb R^2$, $\mathbb R^*=\mathbb R$ and $(\mathbb R^2)^*=\mathbb R^2$, clearly $\mathbb R^2$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R$

Comment: Thanks for pointing at this, if any of you post it as an answer, I would accept it for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (2) one can only deduce that there is a map $q:\ell_\infty^* \to c_0^*$.  You don't know that the map is one-one.  And actually it is onto.  Using this, you can show that $c_0^*$ is a complemented subspace of $\ell_\infty^*$.

Answer (score 1):

$c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell_\infty$, and by virtue of Hahn-Banach, every element of $(c_0)^*$ extends to an element of $(\ell_\infty)^*$, and it does so in infinitely many ways. In particularly, there is (using Zorn's Lemma) an injection
$$
j: (c_0)^*\to (\ell_\infty)^*.
$$